# Modal verb without auxiliary verb

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

I'm used to seeing modal verbs followed by auxiliary verbs, like this:

> I should have been reading.

However, I've heard people say things like:

> I'm glad you did or I wouldn't met you.
>
> I knew we shouldn't trusted him.

Is this construction without the auxiliary informal?

Is there a difference if I rewrite those sentences as:

> I'm glad you did or I wouldn't **have** met you.
>
> I knew we shouldn't **have** trusted him.

Comment: You surely must be mishearing, or listening to speakers of some dialect that is not Standard English. Those are not informal: they are completely ungrammatical and wrong in Standard English, and I have never heard them before.

Comment: It's standard English to reduce auxiliary _have_ by contracting with a preceding modal; there are even standard eyd-dialect spelling for them: _shoulda, shouldna, woulda, wouldna, coulda, couldna, musta,_ etc. That final shwa is very easily lost in speech, especially after a prior syllabic negative contraction, and since the past participle already marks the ghost of the auxiliary, it's not really necessary and may be sacrificed to save a syllable. If you're not a native listener, you may miss the hints; some people swallow unstressed syllables all the time.

Comment: @JohnLawler Because in some (many?) speakers the only stop remaining in those *shouldna*-type “words” is a glottal one, not a *t* or *d* or even a flap, I imagine that would be even harder for non-native listeners to read as a clue if they weren’t accustomed to that particular phenomenon.

Comment: fæspitʃrulz work in multifarious ways, their wəndərstupərfɔrm.

Comment: Following on from John's point, since the poster is called "José", it might also be pertinent to point out that Spanish has epenthetic vowels in some cases that don't actually represent a separate word (notably before sibilant-stop clusters, e.g. in "(e)scanear" there is an optional 'e' vowel). These are never schwas in Spanish. But nonetheless, it is a reasonable hypothesis that a Spanish listener will be more used to 'tuning out' epenthetic vowels and so less used to listening out for the vowel in e.g. "would(a)" as 'a separate word'.

Comment: There's also no need to single out Spanish necessarily: other languages have similar phenomena of epenthetic vowels, another 'mainstream language' case being the French schwa in e.g. "cart*e* d'or" (whereas ordinarily, spoken in isolation, you wouldn't expect the 'e' vowel on the end of "carte" to actually represent a vowel-- it is essentially "silent").

Comment: Thank you for the heads up!
I actually did mishear, the person in my first sentence says "'m glad you did or I wouldna met you." The other person says "I knew we shouldn't trust him." Which actually rises another question, but that's for another topic.
I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation of what you heard is that the speaker was mushing "n't" and "have" into something that sounded like "n'ta":

> I'm glad you did or I wouldn'ta met you.
>
> I knew we shouldn'ta trusted him.

This is *never* written as such even though various American dialects will speed over this contraction so quickly a non-native would not have heard it.

Answer (score -1):

Those sentences are invalid in American, because the verb tenses conflict with each other.
The future & past versions of these words need to match.

```
PAST-------------------------FUTURE
"would have met"----- versus "will meet"    
"should have trusted" versus "should trust"
```